# while trying to signin using postaman it throws as error of csrf token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

when I try to login using a browser it works correctly but, when I try to user Postman to post username & password it throws csrf token error.

[image]

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    .......
      ]
```

Middlewares

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

]
```

When I access the api from a browser is allows me to log in.

Currently not using any Permission classes and authentication_classes.

but tested with rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication at the begining.

Currently not using any.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django needs the crsf_token in all the submitted forms to any views to ensure that the request comes from a legitimate place, so there are several questions here:

**1) Why it works from the browser?**

Probably, this is because you have a line `{% csrf_token %}` in your template.html after the `<form>` tag. This is the way to say to django that it must include a cookie called 'csrf_token' when returning the rendered template. So, when the form is submitted, it takes the cookie 'csrf_token' and includes it in the POST request. When the request is in the server side, django checks that the csrf_token is in the request header and allows the request to continue normally.

This is done automatically and you don't need to care about it only if you include the line `{% csrf_token %}` after the `<form>` tag.

**2) Why it does not work from postman?**

When you send a post from postman, you're not sending the csrf_token in the requests header but you only send the `{'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'}` and django rejects the requests since it has no way to know that the request come from a trustworthy place.

**3) How can you make the login work from postman?**

I see 2 options here.

1. You can first execute a GET to the login template from postman, and you will see that it returns a cookie called csrf_token. Then you can copy that cookie to include it in your request header. (You can configure postman to save the cookie headers and use them in future requests)
2. You can use the decorator `@csrf_exempt` in your view to say django not to check the csrf_token for any view. Here is more info about it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/
   But I would not recommend do this in a login view since it could cause that any login request will be accepted regardless of its origin, causing strongly insecure platforms.